# perceptron algorithm how to calculate input values

Tags: algorithm, neural-network, decision-tree, nearest-neighbor, perceptron

[XYZ Graph hyperlane]

Find according to

1.Nearest beighbour
2.Perceptron algorithm
3.Decision tree
4.Neural Network

Given:

X1  X2  X3  |y 
     0   0   0   |1 
     2   3   4   |0 
    -1   5   9   |0 
     6   3  -1   |1 
     3   3   3   |?

```html
 X1  X2  X3  |y <br/>
 0   0   0   |1 <br/>
 2   3   4   |0 <br/>
-1   5   9   |0 <br/>
 6   3  -1   |1 <br/>
 3   3   3   |?
```

How to
find ? (y value, the unknown) then 
calculate the values with mathematical models.

W_(vector)new=W_old+(delta).(y)[abc]=any value>0

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: how to calculate the inputs or how to find y? value the last one.

Comment: M(A)= (y)[w1x1+w2x2......][abc]?